# shinobi charts - adding symbols and a legend

Tags: objective-c, shinobi

I have been using shinobi charts in iOS and I have a line graph in my app - I would now like to add some symbols to the data points and a legend to explain what the symbols mean - If someone could point me to some sample code that would be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a datasource method which you can use to provide a `UIImage` for each of the data points:

```
- (UIImage *)sChartTextureForPoint:(ShinobiChart *)chart
                  dataPointAtIndex:(NSInteger)dataIndex
                  forSeriesAtIndex:(NSInteger)seriesIndex
```

If you implement this then you can provide the symbols as you wish.

The legend is a little more difficult. A legend is usually designed to allow identification of distinct *series*, however in this instance you would like to identify specific points. This isn't functionality currently supported by Shinobi, and although it would be possible to implement it using the `SChartLegend` class, I think you would be better off creating your own subclass of `UIView` as a legend.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I will check this out. (If anyone else feels like showing me some sample code I'd appreciate that too.)